# how to run cassandra repair/compact from one node in a cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, nodetool

I want to run repair/compact operation from 1 Cassandra cluster node instead of scheduling it from all nodes in a cluster. 
I am using cassandra 3 version.
`"nodetool -h **NODEIP** repair keyspace"` is not working if I specify other node in the cluster. This command only works for the local node which I run this command. Please suggest a way to run repair/compaction for all nodes by running from one node in a cluster.

Thanks

Comment: what error are you getting while using `nodetool -h <ip> repair <keyspace>`

Comment: I am getting "
nodetool: Failed to connect to '<IP>:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'. " Error.
Only command which works is : "bin/nodetool -h localhost repair <keypsace>"
It is not resolving ipaddress.

Comment: If you first investigate why the target node can't receive the local node request, you may not need a workaround. Have you tried that?

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/cstarTroubleshooting/connectionsFail.html

Comment: Yes I tried. Even the local node is not working if i specify IP Address.
Not Working :- "nodetool -h <ip> repair keyspace"
Working:- "nodetool -h localhost repair keyspace"
I tried adding JVM_OPTS = "$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP Address" in cassadra-env.sh but still problem presists

Comment: Just to check, but I suppose that the target node is receiving requests? If yes, ping the 7199 port in the target node, and if you don't get reply check to see if your firewall has a rule for that port.

Comment: Just to close this thread I need to enable JMX port in all nodes. Then I can run repair job from 1 node in cluster. By default JMX port is disabled

Answer (score 2):

By default JMX security is disabled and accessible only from localhost, as nodetool uses JMX to communicate with Cassandra, nodetool will only work on the local node unless JMX security is enabled.

See this Datastax page on how to [enable JMX authentication](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/secureJmxAuthentication.html).